# Doing Math with Dates given in the problem

Tags: sql, oracle

The following is the query and code attached to the query.I am not able to figure out how to use the date 31-dec-2006 in the problem.

For each rental property, list the address, include street, city, state. 
Also list rental type and number of days listed as "Number of Days Listed". Order results by rental type ascending and number of days listed descending. 
Instead of using today's date to determine days listed, use 31-dec-2006

The issue is that Im not receiving any results for this query. I believe I am doing something wrong in the where statement. Im not sure how to assigne a value to the date.

```
select rp_street, rp_city, rp_state, rp_type, (rp_datelisted - sysdate) as "Number of Days Listed"  
from rentproperty
where sysdate = '31-dec-2006'
order by rp_type asc, "Number of Days Listed" desc;
```

Comment: Please provide sample output and desired result.

Comment: Also please mention the issue you are facing.

Comment: where sysdate = '31-dec-2006' condtion is false that is why no output!!

Comment: SYSDATE is a pseudo-column - a function - which returns the **current** date and time. The only time `sysdate = '31-dec-2006'` was true was midnight on 31st December 2006.

Answer (score 2):

When working with dates, then work with dates, not strings. `'31-dec-2006'` is just a string. It *looks* like a date (to us, humans), Oracle will try to convert it to a date (if it can), but you can never be sure it'll work. For example, it won't work in my database:

```
SQL> select count(*) From emp where hiredate < '31-dec-2006';
select count(*) From emp where hiredate < '31-dec-2006'
                                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

If I fix several things, it will work:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = english;

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mon-yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select count(*) From emp where hiredate < '31-dec-2006';

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL>
```

Therefore, either use a date literal (which always looks like `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'`), or apply the `TO_DATE` function to a string, with appropriate format mask, e.g. `to_date('31.12.2006', 'dd.mm.yyyy')` and your query will *always* work.

---

Here's what you could have done (I shortened the column list); the `RENTPROPERTY` CTE lists some sample data; you need code from line 7 onwards.

```
SQL> with rentproperty (rp_street, rp_type, rp_datelisted) as
  2    (select 'Oak street' , 'Type A', date '2000-01-25' from dual union all
  3     select '31st street', 'Type B', date '2001-10-30' from dual union all
  4     select 'Elm street' , 'Type B', date '2004-08-25' from dual union all
  5     select 'Bee street' , 'Type A', date '2006-11-30' from dual
  6    )
  7  select rp_street,
  8         rp_type,
  9        (date '2006-12-31' - rp_datelisted) days_listed
 10  from rentproperty
 11  where rp_datelisted < date '2006-12-31'
 12  order by rp_type asc, days_listed desc;

RP_STREET   RP_TYP DAYS_LISTED
----------- ------ -----------
Oak street  Type A        2532
Bee street  Type A          31
31st street Type B        1888
Elm street  Type B         858

SQL>
```

Comment: Probably they still need a WHERE clause. Maybe `where rp_datelisted < date '2006-12-31'`.

Comment: Probably; fixed. Thank you, @APC.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle, sysdate is the current date, so unless today is 31-dec-2006, you'll never get any results.  If you've used "sysdate" as the column name, try putting it in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

sysdate = '31-dec-2006' condtion is false that is why no output!!

this is probably what you need:

```
select rp_street, rp_city, rp_state, rp_type, (rp_datelisted - sysdate) as "Number of 
Days Listed"  
from rentproperty
where  rp_datelisted= '31-dec-2006'
order by rp_type asc, "Number of Days Listed" desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

The Oracle sysdate returns date and time.  Try trunc(sysdate) to compare similar values.

```
select rp_street, rp_city, rp_state, rp_type, (rp_datelisted - sysdate) as "Number of Days Listed"  
from rentproperty
where trunc(sysdate) = '31-dec-2006'
order by rp_type asc, "Number of Days Listed" desc;
```

Comment: Unless we're futzing with the server's internal clock, `sysdate` will never again equal `date '2006-12-31'`. Truncating it won't change that calendrical truth.

Comment: I assumed that was a given.  My mistake.  But it holds true that you must compare like values and DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS is not the same as DD/MM/YYYY.